# Handling a follow-up question due to an error in the original answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420603/confidence-intervals-positioned-central-on-a-group-bar) is a follow-up question from the same user to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316893/how-to-compute-confidence-intervals-and-plot-them-on-a-bar-plot).  The OP made the follow-up question because the answer to the original (which the OP marked as correct) doesn't quite produce the desired behavior.  I took a look at the code in the original answer, and found:

- I couldn't reproduce the OP's issue in the second question
- I couldn't get the answer to the first question to work without modifying the code
- I could fix the code in the original answer via a tiny modification (likely an accidental omission in the answer due to an environmental variable)

It's fair to say the original answer is incomplete, albeit just barely, but someone not well-versed in the language (Matlab) might not realize this.  It's also fair to say the OP's second question may indicate an issue that isn't identifiable based on the material provided in the second question, though I have a pretty good guess as to why the second question looks the way it does.

I see a LOT of different ways to address these two questions, but it's not at all clear to me which is preferred.  For now, I've added a new answer to the original question and put a comment in the second question linking back to it.

**EDIT 1**
...also I just noticed the OP has a broken hyperlink in the second question that, when fixed (change the leading bit to `https://`), resolves to a blocked site (certificate error)...so, I assume I shouldn't fix the broken link, but should it be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't (of course) speak for the whole Community but, in the case you point out, where only a very minor 'tweak' is required to the original answer, what I would do is point out the error (and provide the required fix) in a *comment* to that answer - rather than posting a near-identical, new answer.

If the OP of that answer doesn't respond to and/or act upon your suggestion after a reasonable amount of time, you would then (IMHO) be justified in editing the post (but do make some **clear** indication of your edit and why you made it).

You could then mention your suggestion/edit as a comment in the second question.

I think it is generally accepted that answers aren't really 'owned' by their OP and, if minor changes make that answer better, then it is surely for the general good of Stack Overflow and its overall quality.

Comment: Should I then mark the second question to be closed as a duplicate (or something)?  Also, I prefer your solution over what I did, but I've had trouble with getting code edits rejected in the past, even when I think they're very small; what's appropriate in the community's eyes still feels fuzzy...

Comment: @TTT If the second question is *very* closely related to the first, then dupe-closing may be appropriate. Otherwise, it could be left open and up to the poster: if they feel satisfied with the modified first answer, they may very well delete their second question.

Comment: @TTT As for editing code in others' answers: Well, there will always be some "fuzz" around that! FWIW, I've had a few of my own answers edited by others, and almost 100% of those changes have improved the answer - so I'm not complaining.

Comment: Note that editing code in questions is really not preferred, because these types of edits can actually edit out the problem! But that is different from answers.

Comment: Now, the **real** question, should proceed to make the recommended changes given that I already put in a new answer?

Comment: @TTT Up to you! But, bear in mind that you *can* delete your new answer (if it's not yet accepted), try another approach, then *undelete* that answer if you get no joy.